# Python | Docker | Django | django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured Error

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, docker

I'm trying to run a python file that is inside a container however I'm getting the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/e2esetup.py", line 2, in <module>
    django.setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 17, in setup
    configure_logging(settings.LOGGING_CONFIG, settings.LOGGING)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Code being run in docker:

```
docker exec -it $DOCKER_ID python /tmp/e2esetup.py
```

My code:

```
import django
django.setup()
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from apps.account.models import Profile
from apps.organisation.models import Organisation
.... 
#rest is fine for sure
```

I'm new to django and docker, from what I can tell I need to set the environment however I don't know how, running through manage.py does this for you or something, so if I were to run a python file through the interpreter, I have to do this manually, however I dont know how.

I also read that I need to pipe the docker environment somehow, but I'm not sure what that means either, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error suggests you need to set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable. It's value should be something like `mysite.settings` (check what it is in `manage.py`).

You can set it in the `Dockerfile`

```
ENV DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE mysite.settings
```

Or in the environment when you

```
docker exec -it -e "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=mysite.settings" $DOCKER_ID python /tmp/e2esetup.py
```

Or in the script itself.

```
import os

import django

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings') 

django.setup()
```